# Excel VBA bold some text on a string based on the text in another cell, experiencing an "Invalid quantifier" error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with investor names where I would like to bold the names that are a lead investor in the "Investor(s)" column, as indicated in another column (Lead Investor(s)). The Lead investor names always appear in the beginning of the text string and in the same sequence as they are listed in the "Lead Investor(s)" column.

| Investor(s) | Lead Investor(s) |
| --- | --- |
| **Tiger**, Insight, General Atlantic | Tiger |
| **SoftBank, Norwest**, Alumni Ventures | SoftBank, Norwest |

I am using the below code but getting an "Invalid qualifier" error on this line:
`Value1.Cells.Characters(start:=1, Length:=BoldLength).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"`

```
Sub BoldInv()
    Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Value1 As String, Value2 As String

    With Worksheets("Output")

        LR1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I4").End(xlUp).Row '<= I is the "Investor(s)" column
        LR2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L4").End(xlUp).Row '<= L is the "Lead Investor(s) column

        For i = 1 To LR1
            Value1 = Range("I" & i)

                For j = 1 To LR2
                    Value2 = .Range("L" & j)
                    BoldLength = Len(Value2)
                    Value1.Cells.Characters(start:=1, Length:=BoldLength).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                Next j
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

How can I resolve this error in this instance?

Comment: `Value1` should be dimmed as a range and set  to `Range("I" & i)`

Comment: Are the 2 columns not the same length ?. Why have 2 `For..Next` loops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub BoldInv()
    Dim LR1 As Long, i As Long, rng As Range, BoldLength As Integer
    'at next line if use -Me- the code must be in sheet's module
    With Me    'or Worksheets("anySheetName")
        LR1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row '<= I is the "Investor(s)" column
        
        For i = 1 To LR1
            Set rng = .Range("I" & i)
            BoldLength = Len(rng.Offset(0, 3).Value)
            rng.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=BoldLength).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```